# Why are `update_add_htlc` and `commitment_signed` separate messages?

Tags: lightning-network

[BOLT #2](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/02-peer-protocol.md#normal-operation) indicates that a node will send one or more `update_` messages before a subsequent `commitment_signed`.

Since it seems like sending a payment over a channel involves `update_add_htlc` followed by `commitment_signed` (without needing a response from the peer in between), why do these need to be two separate messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `commitment_signed` message is also used at other places to move forward channel state. The entire process is not only described in BOLT02 but also in Mastering lightning

https://github.com/lnbook/lnbook/blob/366a65b33045cbb9e95a3d4060005c240f1f1778/channel-operation.asciidoc

There you can see that after Alice sends and `update_add_htlc` message and a `commitment_signed` message Bob will later in the protocol also send a `commitment_signed` message so that Alice can also move forward her state. Remember Bob and Alice both have an asymmetrical version of the commitment transaction for each state and both need a signature from the other side. It would be strange if Bob replied with an `update_add_htlc` message to send over signatures even though he does not want to add an htlc.

So yes while signatures could have been included in the `update_add_htlc` message we still would have needed the  `commitment_signed` for Bob to reply. Also when stetteling htlcs the `commitment_signed` messages are needed again. I guess in that way it seems more reasonable to make the exchange of signatures explicit with its own message instead an reusing it. But of course that was a choice that could have been taken differently.